# probability they knew the donut door

Tags: probability

100 people choose a door to walk through. each time there are two doors to choose from. every time one door has a donut behind it. If they smell which door has the donut behind it, they choose that door. otherwise the choose a random door.

the donut is randomly placed every time behind a new door, there is no residue effect or other bias in decision making.

70 people went through the donut door.

What is the probability that they smell the donut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We expect exactly half the non-smellers to go through the door, and all of the donut-smellers to go through the donut door. Thus, we can set up a system of equations in number of smellers ($S$) and non-smellers ($N$):

$$\begin{cases}S+\frac12N = 70\\S+N = 100\end{cases}$$

Solving this yields that $S=40$ and $N = 60$: there are $40$ smellers and $60$ non-smellers.

Hence, there is a $\frac{40}{100}$ chance that a randomly chosen person from the hundred is a donut-smeller.

Feel free to ask for further clarification if you don't understand anything in this answer.

Comment: The non-smellers COULD go many ways other than 50/50. Maybe no on can smell donuts and the 70/30 distribution was just by chance...

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires "If they smell which door has the donut behind it, they choose that door. otherwise the choose a random door." Choosing a random door has a 50% success rate.

Comment: On average. But you can not be sure.